# Users unable to use their printer on Remote Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server

For some reason I have two users that can not use their local printer.  I can't even add it for them when they are logged in.  Has anyone seen this happen before?

What do I need to check on on the terminal server to make sure this is allowed? I have the printer box checked on the RDP client session.

Thanks

Comment: You should take a peek as [ask]. As it currently stands, this is a pretty terrible question.

Answer (score 4):

Why, yes. Yes, I have. Why do you ask?